# How do I go about designing this type of stingers?

Tags: stingers

Hey there, fellow social sound designers.

I'm coming to you with a practical question. How do I go about designing this type of radio-ish stingers: http://soundcloud.com/georgevlad/stingers/s-l11QP

(That is not my work, and it's only there to show you what I mean.)

I'm interested in those short bursts and transitions, but also in the dynamics of everything. Is there a specific effect or set of effects that can simply turn music, noise or other audio into something like this? Do you have any experience with similar stuff?

I'm asking this because I'd like to avoid reinventing the wheel when a solution may be right in front of me. It is possible however that this can only be done with endless hours of toil and work. If this is the case then please let me know and I will get right on to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those sound a bit like what can be achieved with one of those Reaktor patches & a lot of experimenting - recording the output and editing combinations etc...
have a listen to the demos of S Layer - it has def some of that overtly annoying/attention seeking style :) 
http://twistedtools.com/shop/reaktor/s-layer/

Answer (score 4):

back in the days when I started to produce my own synth patches I red many books concernin substractive synthesis. This book is by far and still very much up to date on substractive synthesis and it will explain all the details you need to know how to operate the somewhat complex beasts. Highly reommended. http://www.amazon.com/Power-Tools-Synthesizer-Programming-Reference/dp/0879307730/ref=pd_sim_b_1

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve most of those synthetic sounds with most substractive synth and by applying LFOs to pitch, filter cutoff,etc. and automate the frequency of the LFOs.

You could also try to load various samples into a sampler and modulate the pitch (and playback speed) of the samples via a LFO.

You might also want to play with very short delays to get those Transformers-like sounds.

Answer (score 2):

sounds like the world you're looking at is the world of radio imaging.

Some super super talented guys work in that world.  There's a good podcast out there called The Producers where they talk about how to build and use that kind of stuff.  Check out the [episode with Joe D'Augustin](http://www.ryanontheradio.com/2011/06/episode-36-%E2%80%93-part-1-%E2%80%93-joe-dagostin/) to hear one of the best talk about his methodology.

I'm currently going through the archives and checking it out.  cool stuff in there.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys, thank all you for your suggestions. I will pick up Jim Aikin's book as it sounds really interesting.

Anyway, reading Tim's comment I remembered that back in the day when I was writing extreme music such as IDM, Glitch, Datkstep etc I made excessive use of these two plugins:

http://illformed.org/plugins/glitch/
http://mdsp.smartelectronix.com/livecut/

And this looked like the best opportunity to revive that abuse. With this in mind I put together a tame mix and applied several instances of these two plugins, on inserts and master as well, plus a bit of compression and brickwall limiting. The result is a cacophony of glitches that I can cut into small bits and use as awesome stingers:

http://soundcloud.com/georgevlad/glitch-madness